# Obtaining population estimates by ZCTA from American Fact Finder

Tags: data, united-states, census, zip-codes

I would like to obtain the most recent population estimates (and age and gender information if possible) at the ZIP Code Tabulation Area (ZCTA) level.

I think this data exists on the [American Fact Finder](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml), but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it. Does anyone have any pointers as to how to extract this data?

Comment: If this is open data then I think it is much more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.